# why isn't this current participle changing form?

Tags: adjective-ending, participle

in https://german.net/reading/gesund-leben/,
I see a sentence,

```
Ein gesunder Körper braucht ausreichend Bewegung.
```

Bewegung is female, so shouldn't it be

```
Ein gesunder Körper braucht ausreichende Bewegung.
```

? Is the text on the site wrong?

Comment: It's *Deklination* (following the noun gender, case and number), not *Konjugation* (following the person, tense and number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting case. The *move test* shows that the word «ausreichend» is an attribute of «Bewegung», not an adverbial phrase:

1. Ein gesunder Körper braucht ausreichend Bewegung.

You can move the entire phrase to the Vorfeld:

2. Ausreichend Bewegung braucht ein gesunder Körper.

The *question test* corroborates that they «ausreichend Bewegung» forms a single constituent:

3. Was braucht ein gesunder Körper? – Ausreichend Bewegung.

The *replacement test* shows what the word *ausreichend* is – it is a **quantifier** (or **quantifying particle)** like «viel» or «wenig»:

4. Ein gesunder Körper braucht viel/wenig/ausreichend Bewegung.

Comment: so you mean it's a quantifier like viel or wenig so that's why it doesn't change its form(no Deklination)? Hm.. that's another explanation. Can any arbitrary adjective/participle be used as quantifier? Could you direct me to the grammar page explaining this? I didn't study advanced grammar yet.

Comment: Sure thing, e.g. *Duden, Grammatik der deutschen Gegenwartssprache,* hrsg. von der Dudenredaktion, 6., neu bearbeitete Aufl., Mannheim, Leipzig, Wien, Zürich: Dudenverl., 1998, S. 278 (§ 472). They are calling these words «[d]ie unbestimmten (indefiniten) Zahladjektive» […] «flexionslos gebraucht». Only very few adjectives can be used in such a way. Apart from *viel, wenig, ausreichend,* only *genug, genügend* come to my mind.

Comment: but I don't see ausreichend in this table : http://www.nemcina.org/download/gh_47.pdf  Are you sure ausreichend is one of them?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. That list is not complete. So what? Not even the Duden grammer (a much better source) is complete.

Comment: I see, I considered Janka's explanation again, but your answer seems more plausible to me now, (because ausreichend is before Bewegug, it looks like a qualifer).

Comment: @ChanKim: The grammatical reasoning is as follows: In the slot before the finite verb (the *Vorfeld* slot), German allows but a single constituent. This is a very useful test for determining what words belong together in the same constituent and what words are constituents by themselves (there are seldom cases where a constituent can be split up). Since «ausreichend Bewegung» can be moved before the finite verb, it must be one constituent, which means that «ausreichend» is a qualifier of (or attribute to) «Bewegung».

Comment: to me, context wise, ausreichend is more confining `Bewegung` than `braucht`. I believe you are right, but if one wrote 'Bewegung bracht ein gesunder Körper ausreichend`, is it nonsense and grammatically wrong?(in English, A Healthy body  sufficiently needs excercise)

Answer (score 1):

*ausreichend* is originally the present participle of *ausreichen*, but today often classified as a self-standing adjective.

German wants adjectives that are *attributes* of substantives to follow the flexing of these substantives. In all other cases, adjectives do **not** follow case, number and genus of the substantive. Your example sentence can be considered as one of these non-attributive usages.

What you observe here is what is called a *Depiktiv*, the *ausreichend* is in this case not a qualifier of the substantive, but rather the predicate and is thus not flexed (You could consider this an *adverbial usage*).

Note your second example is not wrong, it just has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: Ok I knew when it is in `subject sein adjective` form, it doesn't change form(predicate?) and understood that when the adjective is before the noun, they should follow the 'flexing' of the noun. But according to your explanation, sometimes it's not. Can you please give me a couple of those non-attribute adjective examples? as an elaboration? (in the answer) That would help many learners.

Comment: Each German adjective can also be used as an adverb, simply by leaving out the adjective's case ending. The same is true for *Partizip I*, which acts as an adjective. The difference in meaning is simple: An adjective describes a noun while an adverb describes the predicate of the sentence. It's *ausreichend brauchen* vs *ausreichende Bewegung*.

Comment: @Janka wow that's a clear explanation. Vielen Dank!

Comment: I am sorry, but this analysis is wrong, as can be shown by the *move test* (Umstellungsprobe). Since «ausreichend Bewegung» can be moved to the slot before the finite verb, it must constitute a single phrase (Satzglied). This means that «ausreichend» functions as an attribute of «Bewegung», and not as an adverbial. If it truly were an adverbial, this would not be possible.