# "für ausreichend Getränke sorgen"

Tags: declension, participle

Ich möchte wissen, weswegen "ausreichend" in diesem Kontext nicht flektiert wird.

Ich habe widersprüchliche Informationen zum Thema gefunden: die einen behaupten, es handele sich dabei um einen Quantor; die anderen behaupten, es handele sich dabei um ein Prädikativum. Ich bin ganz verwirrt.

Comment: _"weswegen "ausreichend" in diesem Kontext nicht flektiert wird."_ Was genau meinst Du mit _flektiert_? Was würdest Du denn (bezüglich einer angewandten Grammatik Regel) konkret erwarten?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, er fragt, warum es nicht "ausreichende Getränke" heißt.

Comment: Verwandt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/welche-wortart-ist-genug https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46283/why-isnt-this-current-participle-changing-form/ https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/if-geld-is-neuter-then-why-not-genuges-geld