# Sollen wir "ausreichend Abstand" oder "ausreichenden Abstand" halten?

Tags: word-usage

Meine Freundin hat mich gerade mit einer Frage überrascht, die ich nicht beantworten konnte.

Um, im Zuge der Corona-Krise, auf den zu haltenden Abstand hinzuweisen, steht auf einem Schild ihrer Firma: "Bitte halten Sie **ausreichenden** Abstand." (1)

Mir ist nur die Form "Bitte halten Sie **ausreichend** Abstand." (2) geläufig, was bei Google auch deutlich mehr Treffer generiert. Nun stellt sich aber die Frage: **Was ist richtig? Oder ist beides richtig?**

Bei näherem Überlegen verstehe ich nicht, was für eine Wortart "ausreichend" im zweiten Fall ist bzw. worauf es sich bezieht. Im Duden steht ausreichend als Adjektiv. Es bezieht sich hier auf den Abstand. Insofern müsste es "ausreichenden Abstand" heißen. Dies wird aber fast nie gebraucht. Vielleicht kann mich jemand aufklären.

Comment: Solche oder ähnliche Fragen haben wir gar nicht so selten: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46283/why-isnt-this-current-participle-changing-form https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/welche-wortart-ist-genug

Comment: Sollen wir sagen "er ist (nicht) ausreichend" oder oder "er reicht (nicht) aus"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Attribut eines Substantivs

> Bitte halten Sie ausreichenden Abstand.

Hier ist das Adjektiv (eigentlich ein Partizip, das spielt hier aber keine große Rolle) ein Attribut des Substantivs *Abstand* und bildet mit diesem gemeinsam eine Nominalgruppe. Das Attribut beschreibt also eine Eigenschaft des Substantivs *Abstand*. In dieser Funktion als Attribut eines Substantivs, und als Teil einer  Nominalgrupe, muss das Adjektiv gebeugt werden.

Das eben Gesagte gilt auch für das Adjektiv "frisch" in diesen Sätzen, das ebenfalls gebeugt werden muss:

> Erich trinkt frisches Wasser.
>   Bitte trinken Sie frisches Wasser.

---

### 2. Attribut eines Verbs

> Bitte halten Sie ausreichend Abstand.

Nicht nur Substantive können durch Attribute beschrieben werden, das ist auch bei Verben möglich:

> Karl fährt **schnell.**

Hier beschreibt das Adjektiv "schnell" auf welche Weise gefahren wird. Diese Verwendung eines Adjektivs heißt *"adverbial".* Man kann auf diese Weise aber nicht nur Adjektive (und damit einhergehend auch Partizipien) als Attribute von Verben einsetzen, sondern auch Wörter, die man (bis auf ganz wenige Ausnahmen) ausschließlich adverbial verwenden kann, nämlich die Adverbien:

> Karl fährt **gern.**

Dass das Wort "ausreichend" ebenfalls als Attribut eines Verbs verwendet werden kann, beweisen diese Sätze:

> Erich trinkt ausreichend.
>   Bitte trinken Sie ausreichend.

Aber eben auch:

> Bitte halten Sie ausreichend Abstand.

Hier beschriebt das Wort keine Eigenschaft des Abstandes, sondern eine Eigenschaft des Haltens.

---

### Nachtrag

Da das Attribut eines Verbs hinter dem Verb steht, das Attribut einen Substantivs aber vor dem Substantiv, und weil hier das Subjekt im Satz nach dem Verb kommt, muss das Wort *ausreichend* bzw. "ausreichenden" zwangsweise an der Position im Satz stehen, an der es steht. Dass sich aufgrund der Formulierung als Bitte das Subjekt direkt hinter das Verb quetscht, macht die Analyse des Satzes nicht gerade einfacher, ändert aber nichts am Kern des Geschehens.

Ich danke Davit Vogt für ein Beispiel, das er in seinem Kommentar zwar mit einer anderen Intention vorgebracht hat, das aber trotzdem sehr gut geeignet ist, den Unterschied zwischen gebeugtem und vorangehendem Attribut eines Substantivs und ungebeugtem und nachfolgendem Attribut eines Verbs herauszustellen. Ich lasse die Formulierung als Bitte weg, weil die Bitte nur einen neuen Grad an Komplexität ins Spiel bringt, der mit der Sache selbst nichts zu tun hat. Dann kann man den Satz von David auf diese beiden Arten schrieben:

1. Sie achten auf ausreichenden Abstand.
2. Sie achten ausreichend auf Abstand.

Hier ist das Wort *»Abstand«* nicht mehr Teil eines Akkusativobjekts, sondern Teil eines Präpositionalobjekts, das durch die Präposition *»auf«* eingeleitet wird, der dann (innerhalb des Präpositionalobjektes) ein Substantiv bzw. eine Nominalgruppe im Akkusativ folgt.

Wenn das Adjektiv ein Teil des Objekts, und somit ein Attribut des Substantivs ist, muss es im Präpositionalobjekt hinter der Präposition stehen und muss gebeugt werden.

Wenn es nicht Teil des Objekts ist, sondern das Verb *»achten«* näher beschreibt, muss es vor dem Objekt stehen, und steht somit vor der Präposition *»auf«*. Und in diesem Fall darf das Wort *»ausreichend«* auch nicht gebeugt werden.

Comment: Gegen 2. sprechen Präpositionalphrasen wie in *bitte achten Sie auf ausreichend Abstand*, in denen man nicht umhinkommt, *ausreichend* unmittelbar auf *Abstand* zu beziehen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Aber ich halte das von dir genannte Beispiel auch für falsch. Richtig müsste es entweder heißen *»Bitte achten Sie auf ausreichenden Abstand«* oder *»Bitte achten Sie ausreichend auf Abstand«.* Und anhand dieser beiden richtigen Sätze sieht man sogar noch viel klarer (nämlich aufgrund der veränderten Position im Satz) in welchem Satz das Wort ein ungebeugtes Attribut eines Verbs oder ein gebeugtes Attribut einen Substantivs ist.

Comment: Die Bewertung, daß Präposition + *ausreichend* (unflektiert) + Nomen falsch sei, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Mir scheint, sie wurde nur getroffen, um die Theorie zu retten. Daß unflektiertes *ausreichend* sich zwingend auf das Verb beziehen müsse, ist dagegen tatsächlich falsch. Bei anderen Verben als *achten* ergibt ein Bezug auf das Verb gar keinen Sinn: *die Betreiber hoffen auf ausreichend Schnee* (Hoffnung auf genug Schnee) ist plausibel, *sie hoffen ausreichend auf Schnee* (genug Hoffnung) hat nicht die beabsichtigte Bedeutung.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Gutes Argument. Aber warum darf denn nun *»ausreichend«* in *»die Betreiber hoffen auf ausreichend Schnee«* ungebeugt bleiben?

Comment: Ich kann das auch nur beobachten, nicht wirklich erklären. Es sieht so aus, als ob *ausreichend* sich *genug* und *viel* angeschlossen hat. Das Gemeinsame ist die quantifizierende Bedeutung, die auch in [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46292/35111) angesprochen wurde.